# CSS3: Creating horizontal line (or border) with icon inside

Tags: css

What I'm willing to achieve is some kind of dividers that are used on http://mintteal.com/ under the captions. There is an icon inside, but I've yet failed to create such horizontal line on both sides.

Comment: What's so difficult about checking the computed styles on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a peek at their HTML/CSS to learn how they did it. Here is what they have:

```html
<div class="title">
    <h1>What We Do</h1>
    <i class="fi-wrench"></i>
</div>
<style>
div.title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.title h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 0;
}
.fi-wrench::before {
    content: "\f215";
    font-family: "foundation-icons";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
div.title i {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border: 3px solid #41c39f;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 37px;
    background: #f4f4f5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps this is what you wanted [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vQJ6N/).**

The divider is made by the `:before` tag. And the content inside makes up the image.